# Encryption in erlang

Tags: encryption, erlang, ejabberd

```
Crypt = crypto:aes_cfb_128_encrypt(Key, IV, Text),
io:format("Crypt is ~p~n", [Crypt]),
B64 = base64:encode(Crypt),
io:format("Crypt B64 is ~p~n", [B64]),
Decrypt = crypto:aes_cfb_128_decrypt(Key, IV, Crypt),
io:format("Decrypt is ~p~n", [Decrypt]),
ok.
```

Is encryption and decryption via these methods in erlang is safe?
I will use this encryption and decryption in mnesia.
If not is there other safer method for encryption and decryption

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with it, you should either have a checksum or a MAC. I'm not familiar with erlang or its crypto module, so I don't know what padding is used, but you should use some padding like PKCS#5/PKCS#7.

Comment: What is your goal? What effect are you trying to achieve? Without knowing that it is very hard to tell what approach is appropriate.

Comment: @ArtjomB. what would the difference between a checksum and a MAC be in this case?

Comment: If you encrypt-then-mac you can securely check whether the ciphertext was changed without first decrypting it. A checksum can only be used over the plaintext and it doesn't include padding, so there are possible attacks. This depends on your attack model and what you actually want to achieve using encryption.